# How to take space separated input in python

Tags: python, input

I want to take the following in single line from user

```
Abc 0 1 0
```

How can this be done? I tried

```
map(int,input().split())
input() and then split
input().split(" ")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    name = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    Abc 0 0 2
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but it is not giving the desired result.

Comment: Have you tried "splitting on space" when you have space-separated input?

Comment: I want to take the input and then split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4 = input().split(“ “)
```

You could directly unpack them in a function like that:

```
func(*input().split(“ “))
```

Comment: I am getting File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    name = input().split(" ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    Abc 0 0 2
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Use # to comment out the first line of code you posted

Answer (score 1):

```
#a = input()
a = "Abc 0 1 0"
inp_list = a.split()
print(inp_list)
```

`input()` returns a list of strings. You have to handle it as such

```
for e in inp_list:
    try:
        e_int = int(e)
    except ValueError:
        print(e)
        continue
    print(e_int)
```

Comment: I am getting File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    name = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    Abc 0 0 2
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Nitika You are getting this error on your own code...

Comment: even when I writing this single line I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Nitika When running my code, you will open a console. In that newly opened console, you have to type your input. Not in the code itself.

Comment: I am doing the same. Can you provide a code snippet with just the input line and then give the input in console?

Answer (score 1):

```
text = input("Say something")
print(text.split())
print(text.replace(" ", ""))
```

output

```
Say somethingthis has spaces but it wont when it is done
['this', 'has', 'spaces', 'but', 'it', 'wont', 'when', 'it', 'is', 'done']
thishasspacesbutitwontwhenitisdone
```

Comment: I want to take input from user